# Python isn't converting io.Bytes variable into a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my python code. I'm trying to download an excel file on a Sharepoint site into a dataframe but I'm facing tons of issues.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import io
import pandas as pd
from config import config

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials
url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/CDNDataAnalysis/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B5F665DDF-032B-4E04-A9F0-7F43CC565D6A%7D&file=NetworkBindings.csv&action=default&mobileredirect=true'
username = config["sp_user"]
password = config["sp_password"]

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print("Authentication successful")

response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj2 = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj2.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj2.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe

#This errors out :/
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj2)

print(type(bytes_file_obj2))
```

The code errors out at this line "df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj2)"  saying the object isn't of excel type. But I found this solution on StackOverflow and it works for them.

The variable "bytes_file_obj2" is of io.BytesIO

Comment: The URL says `file=NetworkBindings.csv`. Are you sure this is actually a `.xls(x)` file, not a plain-text CSV? You can open CSVs in Excel, sure, but Excel files and CSVs are very different

Comment: @ForceBru - I changed my code at the end to "df = pd.read_csv(bytes_file_odj2)" but I still run into a error. This is the error: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data.

Comment: Have you tried printing `response.content`? Maybe it's human readable? What does it look like? Illegible garbage (binary) or something that makes sense?

Comment: I did. Strangely, I get what appears to be some html headers like so "'\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang="en-us" dir="ltr" class="ms-isBot">\r\n   <head>\r\n\t\t<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />\r\n\t\t<meta name="viewport""

Comment: You could save that to an `.html` file and render it in your browser. I bet authentication failed, and you're getting some kind of "Input your login and password" page

Comment: I saved the contents of response.content.decode("utf-8") as a html. When I open the html file on a browser, I can see the csv file with all the data I need.  https://imgur.com/gallery/ulsLhbt       How would I save this html as a csv?

Comment: You could try [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem where HTML code is returned instead of the Excel file is usually due to an issue with the way the URL is formatted. The URL you pass to ClientContext allows you to be authenticated while the URL you pass to the File.open_binary() function should be a file path to the Excel file on the server. Try changing the URL to

```
url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/CDNDataAnalysis/'
```

Getting the path to the file can be done by opening the file and going

File > Share > Share with People > Copy Link

If you examine the link it should contain the path. You'll need to remove any URL sanitization. For example, spaces will be replaced with "%20" and you'll need to change them back to spaces. Based on your code, the final path might look something like

```
response = File.open_binary(ctx, 'sites/CDNDataAnalysis/Shared Documents/NetworkBindings.xlsx')
```

The URL parser is finicky so you may need to experiment by adding or removing elements of the URL and file path before it works.